# how to prevent page from scrolling back up when a button is clicked

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site that is using twitter bootstrap's carousel example found here http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/carousel.html

Below the carousel, I've added another section using their fluid row.  Basically, in this new row I've added 3 divs.  Each div has a form embedded in it.  here's one div as an example:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span4 package">
        <h2>Package 1</h2>
        <p>A basic package that ....includes blah blah blah </p>
          <ul>
          <li>a</li>
          <li>br</li>
          <li>c</li>
          <li>d</li>
          </ul>
        </p><br/>
        <p><a class="btn btn-info" href="#" id="q1btn">Request a Quote &raquo;</a></p><br/>

          <div id="quote1">
              <form action="quote.php" method="post">
                  <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                      <td width="29%" class="bodytext">Name:</td>
                      <td width="71%"><input name="name" type="text" id="q1name" size="32" autofocus></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class="bodytext">eMail:</td>
                      <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="32"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class="bodytext">Message:</td>
                      <td><textarea name="comment" cols="45" rows="6" id="comment" class="bodytext"></textarea></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class="bodytext"> </td>
                      <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send"></td>
                  </tr>
                  </table>
              </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I'm using jquery to toggle the visibility of this form... like so:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#quote1').hide();
  });

  $("#q1btn").click(function() {
      $('#quote1').toggle();
      $('#q1name').get(0).focus();
  });
```

Everything works, eventhough this might not be the best way to do it. (I'm planning on changing the table in the form to divs...)

But the one thing I can't figure out is why the page automatically scrolls back to the top when I click on the Request a Quote button. 
I have to then scroll back down to the page to see the form.  I thought setting focus on the name field in the form would resolve it but it's not making a difference.

Is it possible that the carousel is causing this?  I noticed that the carousel code includes logic somewhere to make the pictures change automatically every few seconds...

Any suggestions would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the default behavior of the `a` tag. to prevent it, there is something called `.preventDefault` that you can apply on the event. Write your function like this :

```
$("#q1btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#quote1').toggle();
    $('#q1name').get(0).focus();
});
```

Notice the `e` in the function braket.

Answer (score 1):

Try preventing the default action of the link.

```
  $("#q1btn").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#quote1').toggle();
      $('#q1name').get(0).focus();
  });
```

Comment: that worked.  can you tell me what i need to google / research to better understand this solution?